# Replacement rule of pure function not working

Tags: replacement

The following code works

```
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y
Thread[xxx[{1, 3, 4}, {10, 20, 30}]] /. xxx -> g
```

I would like to use

```
Thread[xxx[{1, 3, 4}, {10, 20, 30}]] /. xxx -> (#1^2+#2)&
```

But it returns unevaluated.  Is there a way to use a pure function in the replacement rule?

Comment: Does this do what you want: `Thread[xxx[{1, 3, 4}, {10, 20, 30}]] /. xxx -> (#1^2 + #2 &)`? Just a slight case of parenthesia...

Comment: @YvesKlett - Thanks, even though & binds backwards correctly, I have gotten uses to the form (expression with slots)& to be the pure function itself.  I forgot how far back & can reach.

Comment: Happens to me all of the time 